# Is it possible for a Bluetooth device/button to wake up an Android phone and take a picture (hands free)?

Tags: camera, wakelock, hands-free

Long story short, I am taking daily progress pictures and I am trying to take a picture with the phone without touching it or using a timer etc. Totally hands free.

The phone is a spare Samsung note 10+ mounted to the bathroom mirror and permanently connected with the back camera facing forward. Touching the phone isn't suitable because it's facing the wall and movement has the chance of bumping the position slightly (not ideal).

After experimenting with Bixby many thanks to the comment by [@Morrison Chang](https://android.stackexchange.com/users/3573/morrison-chang), I found it does work hands-free suitably for my partner and myself, however listening to my partner trying to tell the wall to take a photo in a slow robotic voice is not optimal. So, the question remains,

Can a Bluetooth attached button wake a phone and trigger a picture to be taken?

<sub>***Note**: I am a career programmer so writing a simple app isn't out of the equation if need be.*</sub>

Comment: Unclear if you tried enabling [Bixby Voice wake-up](https://www.samsung.com/us/support/answer/ANS00080448/) and using a Bixby voice command to take a picture.

Comment: @MorrisonChang updated. Yes, thanks a lot for that, the bixby voice command does work for both of us, and we will fall back to bixby if need be., though I'm still curious about a Bluetooth button (remote camera button)

Comment: Based on [Android Doze Mode - Bluetooth](https://stackoverflow.com/q/35956260/295004) and accounting for https://dontkillmyapp.com/samsung it seems possible. Found https://github.com/michaelruck/ESP32_phone_camera_remote_shutter but Doze mode / holding wake lock would need to be tested. Accessing Bixby is via a Samsung feature means less concern about waking up phone/camera app.

Comment: @MorrisonChang thanks once again, very interesting, yeah it seems the sleeping might be an issue, agreed that Bixby would likely bypass that, however, that raises the question, the phone must be processing audio all the time for Bixby to wake :/ not that it's a bit deal.

Comment: See my answer to [Does Android hold audio in RAM when listening for ‘hey google’?](https://android.stackexchange.com/q/247675/3573) for references as to how 'wake words' work. The github project references [the remote control feature of the open camera app](https://opencamera.org.uk/help.html#remote_control). You may want to try with a bluetooth keyboard to see if you can make it work.